# mongodb aggregate distinct count

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Realise this topic has been asked many times - but the advice hasn't helped me solve this problem.

The following query is trying to determine the presence of sales on a given weekday using ISODay.  Because the query will be run at the start of the month, I need to know how many occurrences of the specific ISOday occur in the month.

```
var query = { eventType: 'Sale', site : 4, tank: 1, txnDate : { "$gt" : new Date('2018-08-01T00:00:00') } };

db.tankevent.aggregate([
          { $match: query },
          { $project : { 
              isoDay: { $isoDayOfWeek: "$txnDate" },
              dayDate: { $dateToString: { format: "%d", date:"$txnDate" } }
              } 
          },
          { $group: 
              { _id : { isoday: "$isoDay", dday: "$dayDate" }, count: { "$sum" : 1 } }
          },
          { $sort: { "_id.isoday": 1, "_id.dday": 1 } }

 ])
```

provides the following output

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "isoday" : 1,
        "dday" : "06"
    },
    "count" : 62.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "isoday" : 1,
        "dday" : "13"
    },
    "count" : 69.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "isoday" : 1,
        "dday" : "20"
    },
    "count" : 72.0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "isoday" : 2,
        "dday" : "07"
    },
    "count" : 75.0
}
```

I am trying to have "count" represent the number of unique "dday" records - so using the output above, I want count to be "3" for isoDay = 1.  At the moment count is reporting number of sales events that occurred for the group combination

Comment: post some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is have the grouping twice.

```
db.tankevent.aggregate([
      { $match: query },
      { $project : { 
          isoDay: { $isoDayOfWeek: "$txnDate" },
          dayDate: { $dateToString: { format: "%d", date:"$txnDate" } }
          } 
      },
      { $group: 
          { _id : { isoday: "$isoDay", dday: "$dayDate" }, count: { "$sum" : 1 } }
      },
      { $project : { 
          isoDay_Final: "$_id.isoday"    
          } 
      },
      { $group: 
          { _id : "$isoDay_Final", count: { "$sum" : 1 } }
      },
      { $sort: { "_id": 1 } }
 ])
```

Comment: For some reason I thought I was limited to one instance of a pipeline stage - you have freed my mind Shravya - Thanks